# JQuery not working in Chrome but Firefox is fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have troubles with simple Javascript code which works in Firefox and not in Chrome.

here is my function

```
function ToggleArrow(id1, id2)
{
    var display = window.getComputedStyle(id1).getPropertyValue('display');

    if (display=="none") {
        $(id2).fadeToggle(100, function(){$(id1).fadeToggle(100);});
    } else {
        $(id1).fadeToggle(100, function(){$(id2).fadeToggle(100);});
    }
}
```

Chrome is actually not even passing the first line.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or equivalent so we can see?

Comment: nope, it's a dynamic content but I can replicate it in jsfiddle. In meantime any idea what could go wrong for Chrome?

Comment: why don't you use jQuery `$(id1).css(display);` to get display property?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery you can use `.is(':visible')`

```
function ToggleArrow(id1, id2)
{
    if (!$(id1).is(':visible')) // If not visible
        $(id2).fadeToggle(100, function(){$(id1).fadeToggle(100);});
    else 
        $(id1).fadeToggle(100, function(){$(id2).fadeToggle(100);});
}
```

[**Simple DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pW943/1/).

Comment: thanks, good to know, I tried it, but again, works like charm in FF but Chrome simply ignores it. When I delete the content of the function and do sipmle alert("here") I'm getting response in chrome as well but Jquery is simply not working in chrome.

Comment: Can you post your `html` here, the elements with id1 and id2, or make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: problem solved. id1 and id2 are image tags, I put them in div wrappers and now it works in chrome as well.